# Using sp_executesql with params complains of the need to declare a variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am attempting to make a stored procedure that uses sp_executesql.  I have looked long and hard [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx), but I cannot see what I am doing incorrectly in my code.  I'm new to stored procedures/sql server functions in general so I'm guessing I'm missing something simple.  The stored procedure alter happens fine, but when I try run it I'm getting an error.

The error says.

```
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
Must declare the table variable "@atableName"
```

The procedure looks like this.

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_TEST]
    @tableName varchar(50),
    @tableIDField varchar(50),
    @tableValueField varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
    SET @SQLString = N'SELECT DISTINCT @aTableIDField FROM @atableName';
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLString,
            N'@atableName varchar(50),
              @atableIDField varchar(50),
              @atableValueField varchar(50)',
            @atableName = @tableName,
            @atableIDField = @tableIDField,
            @atableValueField = @tableValueField;
END
```

And I'm trying to call it with something like this.

```
EXECUTE sp_TEST 'PERSON', 'PERSON.ID', 'PERSON.VALUE'
```

This example isn't adding anything special, but I have a large number of views that have similar code.  If I could get this stored procedure working I could get a lot of repeated code shrunk down considerably.

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:** I am attempting to do this for easier maintainability purposes.  I have multiple views that basically have the same exact sql except the table name is different.  Data is brought to the SQL server instance for reporting purposes.  When I have a table containing multiple rows per person id, each containing a value, I often need them in a single cell for the users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work but is not advisable unless you are just trying to learn and experiment.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_TEST]
    @tableName varchar(50),
    @tableIDField varchar(50),
    @tableValueField varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
    SET @SQLString = N'SELECT DISTINCT ' + quotename(@TableIDField) + ' FROM ' + quotename(@tableName);
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLString;
END
```

Read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: The part about "select * from @tablename" described what I'm trying to do for maintainability purposes.  I have 10s-100s fields which are exported from a multivalued database.  These are exported from the vendor product, and placed in tables that have a person id and value per row.  For reporting purposes code is often written to pull all of those values into one.  Since the same code is being written everywhere I thought it might be easier to maintain by writing this recurring trend in one place.  Should I suck it up and let the same structure repeat everywhere?

Comment: @wibbe01, Go through the linked article in the post. Dynamic SQL has its place but is dangerous if not used properly especially like passing table names and column names. It is extremely prone to SQL injection. It might be much safer to have some code generation tool to generate the SPs in your situation. However, if you do decide to go this route, be extremely careful.

Answer (score 5):

You can not parameterise a table name, so it will fail with @atableName

You need to concatenate the first bit with atableName, which kind defeats the purpose fo using sp_executesql

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I will be doing it differently then.  The full query I'm trying to do here is quite a bit longer.  Are you saying concatenating that table name everywhere I need it should be done in a different way than using sp_executesql?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: See Andriy M's answer: but this opens you up to SQL injection. Personally I wouldn't bother and have several objects in my database

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use variables to pass table names and column names to a dynamic query as parameters. Had that been possible, we wouldn't actually have used dynamic queries for that!

Instead you should use the variables to *construct* the dynamic query. Like this:

```
SET @SQLString = N'SELECT DISTINCT ' + QUOTENAME(@TableIDField) +
                  ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName);
```

Parameters are used to pass *values*, typically for use in filter conditions.